# How can a smart contract deployed on Mainnet know if it is running on PoW or (in the future) PoS?

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, mainnet

I'd like my smart contract to know if it's running on PoW or (in the future) PoS in Mainnet. Does checking for `block.difficulty` solve the problem?

If so, what will be the value of `block.difficulty` after Mainnet moves to PoS?

Answer (score 1):

Difficulty will be 0 (zero), see https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3675#block-structure.